# UICollectionView: One Row or Column

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uicollectionview

I want to use `UICollectionView` to display a horizontal scrollable list of thumbnails, however, I want this to be a single row. On another view, I'm displaying the thumbnails in a `UICollectionView` but this one scrolls vertically and it's in a single column.

Currently, the way I'm doing this is by changing the size of the collection view to only be big enough for one item so it autowraps and works, but now I'm dealing with variable sized items so it doesn't work anymore.

How do you make a `UICollectionView` display one row or column?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I am guessing you are using the built in `Flow Layout`.
However, for your case, you should make a custom `UICollectionView Layout`.
Make it subclass of `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` and add this code in the `init` method:

```
- (id)init {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        self.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal;
        self.minimumLineSpacing = 10000.0f;
    }
    return self; 
}
```

The `minimumLineSpacing` is the key to making it have one line here.

I hope this helps!

Comment: do you know how this affects intrinsic content size?  I am trying to implement a single row collection view as a slide up / pop over, and constrain it to its minimum intrinsic size for a single row.  Thanks!

Comment: In case anyone wonders why this isn't working for them and you set the class from inside a storyboard, try doing this inside of 
    -(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{}
instead

Comment: +1 - One note is that you don't need to subclass for this (at least I didn't).  In initializing my collection view, I did `flow.minimumInterItemSpacing = CGFloat_Max;`

Comment: I think `self.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal;` is the key to make it one line here. Can you please explain this one?

Comment: Finally I found a worked solution in 2021. I think it gives a very big space value then there is no space for the second row/line. That is why it produces a single row/line. BTW, u don't need to subclass it, set it when you declare your `layout`     `UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    layout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal;
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = CGFLOAT_MAX;`

Answer (score 13):

I found that setting the `minimumLineSpacing` just made my scroll area really big and that setting the `minimumInteritemSpacing=big` accomplished keeping the items in one scrolling row or column, centered in the middle of the `collectionview`.

Comment: @giorashc, this is because it it laying out sideways, so a row would would be laid out vertically in this case.  Hence setting a large value for minimumInterItemSpacing would require more space than the screen is tall, and it would break into multiple lines, horizontally.

Answer (score 9):

There isn't a real reason to subclass if you can trust the type cast.

```
((UICollectionViewFlowLayout *)self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout).minimumLineSpacing = 1000.0f;
```

If you have your collectionView loaded from a nib you could also play around with the parameters in the Attributes and Size Inspectors.

Same goes for scroll direction.

Answer (score 9):

In iOS 13, thanks to UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout, this is trivial, because you can *specify* the number of cells per column in a horizontal layout, or the number of cells per row in a vertical layout. Here's a simple example for a single horizontally scrolling, vertically centered row of cells:

```
func layout() -> UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout {
    let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(
        widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1),
        heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1))
    let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)
    let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(
        widthDimension: .absolute(75),
        heightDimension: .absolute(75))
    let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.vertical(
        layoutSize: groupSize, subitem: item, count: 1) // *
    group.edgeSpacing = NSCollectionLayoutEdgeSpacing(
        leading: nil, top: .flexible(0),
        trailing: nil, bottom: .flexible(0))
    let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
    section.interGroupSpacing = 65
    let config = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayoutConfiguration()
    config.scrollDirection = .horizontal
    let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout(
        section: section, configuration:config)
    return layout
}
```

Set your collection view's `collectionViewLayout` to the output of that function call and you're all set.

Comment: Thank-you for this. For anyone needing to know how to plug this in, add the function to the view controller and set your collection view like this: yourCollection.collectionViewLayout = layout()

Comment: @Marcy Good addition, thanks. I'll just add a clarifying sentence too.

Comment: Thanks a lot @matt, Marcy, the collectionview configurations always baffled me 

Comment: Thanks for this great info.   One detail for anyone doing **TVOS** there's a weird bug or misbehavior with it not lining up on cell zero, unless you use a subclass.  Also the left content inset is screwed on TVOS.  I put in an answer

Answer (score 7):

When you init your `UICollectionView` pass the following `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` in the init parameter.

Note: You do not need to create a subclass of `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`

```
var collectionViewFlowControl = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
collectionViewFlowControl.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirection.Horizontal
```

For 0 px Cell Spacing:

```
collectionViewFlowControl.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0;
collectionViewFlowControl.minimumLineSpacing = 0;

collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 120), collectionViewLayout: collectionViewFlowControl)
```

Answer (score 3):

For Swift 3

```
let flowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
flowLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width/2-10, height: 190)
flowLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 5, 0, 5)
flowLayout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirection.horizontal
flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0.0
self.gCollectionView.collectionViewLayout = flowLayout
```

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me to get a single row of cells regardless of the height of the CollectionView. Set the Min spacing for cells to 1000

[image: Storyboard UICollectionView]

Answer (score 2):

I wanted one column, left aligned and the other answers didn't help me.

So here is my very simple solution for one column, left aligned:

```
class GCOneColumnLeftAlignedFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
    override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
        let attributes = super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect)

        var y: CGFloat = sectionInset.top
        attributes?.forEach { layoutAttribute in
            layoutAttribute.frame.origin.x = sectionInset.left
            layoutAttribute.frame.origin.y = y
            y = y + layoutAttribute.frame.height + minimumLineSpacing
        }

        return attributes
    }
}
```

you also should set something like

```
estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: 120, height: 40)
```

Don't forget to remove the line

```
minimumLineSpacing = big number
```

From the other solutions.

Hope this is helpful because it's a completely different approach compared to the other answers.

Comment: @Fattie all missing at the bottom (or top)? Many years since I cared about this topic. As far as I remember the problem is that the collectionView uses estimated values to determine what area to redraw. You might have to makes sure that the estimated sizes are larger than the calculated sizes.

Comment: cheers @GerdCastan !  you know what, I think the issue I was having was a Mac-Catalyst bug or issue.  I actually deleted my comment to avoid confusing others. **This is indeed the correct approach** , using the CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude "trick" is a bit of a trick.  But there may be some catalyst issues (Catalyust is rapidly evolving, and for most reading this in a year or two it will be irrelevant) Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

I think the documentation is the best :

`minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt`:

*For a vertically scrolling grid, this value represents the minimum spacing between successive rows. For a horizontally scrolling grid, this value represents the minimum spacing between successive columns. This spacing is not applied to the space between the header and the first line or between the last line and the footer.*

`minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt`:

*For a vertically scrolling grid, this value represents the minimum spacing between items in the same row. For a horizontally scrolling grid, this value represents the minimum spacing between items in the same column. This spacing is used to compute how many items can fit in a single line, but after the number of items is determined, the actual spacing may possibly be adjusted upward.*

So if your `scrollDirection` is horizontal, you need to set `minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt` to `CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude` and if your `scrollDirection` is vertical, you need to set `minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt` to `CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude` for getting one row `collectionView`

Comment: Except you should set `minimumInteritemSpacing` (or use `minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt`) regardless of  whether it scrolls horizontally: as you quote, "For a vertically scrolling grid, this value represents the minimum spacing between items in the same row".

Comment: @androidguy I just copied apple documentation not mine!

Answer (score 0):

```
 UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout=[[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
 [layout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal];

 layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0;
 layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0;


 blendEffectCollectionView=[[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 95, 320, 60) collectionViewLayout:layout];
 [blendEffectCollectionView setDataSource:self];
 [blendEffectCollectionView setDelegate:self];
 [blendEffectCollectionView registerClass:[BlendModeCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier"];
 [blendEffectCollectionView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

 [bottomActivityView addSubview:blendEffectCollectionView];
```

Answer (score 0):

#### 2022, for anyone using TVOS

Thanks to the great answer from @matt we know how to do this now.

I found two insurmountable problems in TVOS project.

1. There's basically a bug where it inserts a large left content inset for some reason. The only way to get rid of it is to override `safeAreaInsets`.
2. Separate issue: Strangely if you just set the layout "inline" in the view controller as in the accepted answer from @matt, there's a bug or misbehaviour where the scroll does not start properly on the left, but in a random central position.  (Even worse if you have many of the collection views on the screen, they all behave erraticlly.) Miraculously if you subclass instead, for some reason that fixes it (I guess due to the bringup order somehow).

Hence

```
class TightCollectionView: UICollectionView {
    override var safeAreaInsets: UIEdgeInsets {
        get {
            return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        }
        set {
        }
    }
```

and then ...

```
    func layout() -> UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout {
        let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .absolute(500), heightDimension: .absolute(300))
        let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)
        
        let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .absolute(500), heightDimension: .absolute(300))
        let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.vertical(layoutSize: groupSize, subitem: item, count: 1) // one count for single row
        
        group.edgeSpacing = NSCollectionLayoutEdgeSpacing(leading: .fixed(0), top: .fixed(0), trailing: .fixed(0), bottom: .fixed(0))
        
        let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
        section.interGroupSpacing = 20
        
        let config = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayoutConfiguration()
        config.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        
        let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout(section: section, configuration:config)
        return layout
    }
```

and thus ...

```
    var bringup: Bool = true // I hate doing this but there's no really solid alternative in UIKit, thanks Apple
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        if bringup {
            collectionViewLayout = layout()
            bringup = false
        }
        super.layoutSubviews()
    }
}
```

Footnote - note that code like this:

```
        // section.contentInsetsReference = .none
        // config.contentInsetsReference = .none
```

Seemingly does nothing at all on TVOS. I fiddled with it for hours.

Footnote

```
.absolute(500)
```

I could really only get solid results on all gen. of TVOS by just setting everything absolutely in the compositional layout.  For now (2022!) it just seems too flakey otherwise.