# Horizontal collection view not working

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, flowlayout, swift4

I have a horizontal UICollectionView, and I want it to have one item per column, all in one row. These items are of varying size. In order to do this, I used this UICollectionViewFlowLayout:

```
let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 50, bottom: 0, right: 50)
layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude
```

Then I initialized my UICollectionView with that layout.

The item sizes are correct, but sometimes they get put in the same column, which is bad. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14256229/7214321), my last line should fix the problem, but it does not. The last line simply makes the items extremely far apart from each other. I also tested using `collectionView.height` instead of `CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude`, but I got the same bad result.

How can I fix this, and might this be a Swift 4 bug? –– **this is in Swift 4**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seemed to fix the problem. I am not sure why this worked but it did :)

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return view.frame.height
}
```