# How to create a horizontal scrolling stackView of UIViews using .Xib files

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, xib

I want to create a horizontal scrolling stackView of UIViews using .Xib files, So far I've created the .Xib storyboard as well as the cocoaTouch class that goes along with it and am having trouble setting it up since this is my first time working with .Xib files.

I want the output to look something like this:
[image: ScrollView Desired result]

But when I run the app it throws this error: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<NSObject 0x6000029f13d0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key itemImage.'` and I don't know why this is happening since I'm very unfamiliar with .Xib files.

I've set the file owner's class to the `WhatsHotTile` class as well as the view itself.

Here is the `WhatsHotTile` class:

```
class WhatsHotTile: UIView {
    @IBOutlet weak var itemName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var itemImage: UIImageView!
}
```

And here is the code where I attempt to create the horizontal scrolling stackView:

```
for shoe in Shoes {
        if shoe.trending == true {
            if let whatsHotTile = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("WhatsHotTile", owner: nil, options: nil)!.first as? WhatsHotTile {
                whatsHotTile.itemName.text = shoe.name
                whatsHotTile.itemImage.image = shoe.image
                whatsHotStackView.addArrangedSubview(whatsHotTile)
            }
        }
    }
```

One thing that I haven't done that may or may not need to be done is adding a blank UIView within the horizontal stackView that's inside of the the scrollView. Is that something that needs to be done or does doing it completely programatically work?

Since this is my first time working with .Xib files could someone explain why this error is occurring / how to fix it as well as what's the proper way to create .Xib files and use them within your code, if so that would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue (I believe) is that only some Cocoa Touch classes support .xib files, and `UIView` is not one of those.  When I opened up Xcode and tried `New File -> Cocoa Touch Class -> Subclass of:  UIView`, it disabled the checkbox for `also create .xib file`.  Some example classes that **do** allow .xib files are the `UITableView` and `UICollectionView`.

Since you're trying to scroll items horizontally, not vertically, I'd guess you don't want a `UITableView`.  This leaves the `UICollectionView`.  This works a lot like the `UITableView`, so using what I already knew about table views, plus this Stack Overflow post linked here:

Q: [UICollectionView: One Row or Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13918276/uicollectionview-one-row-or-column)

A: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32584637/18248018

and A: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59206057/18248018

I got it to work the way you described.  Here is a simple working example:

First, create a new Cocoa Touch class file as a subclass of `UICollectionView`, and check the 'also create .xib file' box.  I named this subclass 'WhatsHotTile', to stay close to your original code.

In the Attributes Inspector panel of the `WhatsHotTile` .xib storyboard, set it a `Reuse Identifier`.  In my example, I used the string `TileReuseIdentifier`.

Design the .xib file however you want:  to recreate your code, I put a `UIImageView` above a `UILabel`.

The `WhatsHotTile.swift` file will replace what was a subclass of `UIView` in your code, with the same two `IBOutlets`:

```
import UIKit

class WhatsHotTile: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var itemName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var itemImage: UIImageView!
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }
}
```

In `Main.storyboard`, place a `UICollectionView` inside your view controller.  It will come already initialized with a prototype cell: set this cell's identifier (in the Attributes Inspector) to the same identifier you chose for the .xib file (in the example, it's `TileReuseIdentifier`.

In the `ViewController` file, create an `IBOutlet` for the `UICollectionView`, and inside `viewDidLoad`, set the collection view's `dataSource` to `self` (referring to the view controller).  Then, and *this is the key step to get the .xib files to work with your code*, `register` the nib for the collection view, using the syntax in the example code below:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
        
   collectionOfShoes.dataSource = self
   collectionOfShoes.register(UINib(nibName: "WhatsHotTile", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "TileReuseIdentifier")
}
```

Then you'll have to implement the data source methods for the collection view.  I usually do this in an extension (included in the complete view controller code at the bottom of this answer).  In addition to the two required methods, also define `numberOfSections` and set it to the length of your 'shoes' array.  Then, set the `numberOfItemsInSection` method to return 1.  In conjunction with the following code inside `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, which happens after `viewDidLoad`, this will cause the collection view to scroll horizontally instead of vertically as it otherwise would:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    // REFERENCE 1:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/32584637/18248018
    // REFERENCE 2:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/59206057/18248018
    let collectionViewFlowControl = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    collectionViewFlowControl.itemSize = CGSize(width: 150.0, height: 150.0)
    collectionViewFlowControl.scrollDirection = UICollectionView.ScrollDirection.horizontal
    collectionOfShoes.collectionViewLayout = collectionViewFlowControl
}
```

After these steps, you should wind up with something not too different from your original code, which looks similar to the image reference you provided as your target behavior.  Here is the complete code inside `ViewController`:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionOfShoes: UICollectionView!
    
    struct Shoe {
        let name: String
        let image: UIImage
    }
    
    var shoes: [Shoe] = [Shoe(name: "Shoe 1", image: UIImage(named: "shoe_1")!), Shoe(name: "Shoe 2", image: UIImage(named: "shoe_2")!), Shoe(name: "Shoe 3", image: UIImage(named: "shoe_3")!), Shoe(name: "Shoe 4", image: UIImage(named: "shoe_1")!), Shoe(name: "Shoe 5", image: UIImage(named: "shoe_2")!), Shoe(name: "Shoe 6", image: UIImage(named: "shoe_3")!), Shoe(name: "Shoe 7", image: UIImage(named: "shoe_1")!), Shoe(name: "Shoe 8", image: UIImage(named: "shoe_2")!), Shoe(name: "Shoe 9", image: UIImage(named: "shoe_3")!)]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        collectionOfShoes.dataSource = self
        collectionOfShoes.register(UINib(nibName: "WhatsHotTile", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "TileReuseIdentifier")
    }
    
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        // REFERENCE 1:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/32584637/18248018
        // REFERENCE 2:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/59206057/18248018
        let collectionViewFlowControl = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        collectionViewFlowControl.itemSize = CGSize(width: 150.0, height: 150.0)
        collectionViewFlowControl.scrollDirection = UICollectionView.ScrollDirection.horizontal
        collectionOfShoes.collectionViewLayout = collectionViewFlowControl
    }
}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return shoes.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let whatsHotTile = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "TileReuseIdentifier", for: indexPath) as! WhatsHotTile
        whatsHotTile.itemName.text = shoes[indexPath.section].name
        whatsHotTile.itemImage.image = shoes[indexPath.section].image
        return whatsHotTile
    }
}
```

A picture of the functioning app:

[image: picture of the collection view running in the simulator scrolled horizontally]

Credit belongs to William T., matt and Ilker Baltaci for the question and answers I referenced to implement the horizontal scrolling functionality.

Comment: As a disclaimer, I'm also a relatively new Swift developer, and this is my first time using the UICollectionView element.  I would welcome any corrections or improvements to my answer from all the Swift experts out there!

Comment: How would I round all corners of the cell? currently I'm rounding the corners and adding a shadow inside of the ```awakeFromNib()``` func but it's only rounding the corners on the left side and not the ones on the right side. How do I get the other two corners rounded as well?

Comment: Of the cell itself, or the image embedded in the cell?  If you just mean the cell, I tried adding the line `self.layer.cornerRadius = 10` inside `awakeFromNib` and it seems to be working for all 4 corners

Comment: I also forgot to mention in the answer that the first thing I did after setting up the collection view .xib file was to drag a `UIView` into it.  Both the image and the label are embedded inside that view.  If you don't have a view behind those elements, it might not work the same

Comment: To round the corners of the `UIImage` inside each cell, you can add the line `whatsHotTile.itemImage.layer.cornerRadius = 10` (or whatever number you want) right before `return whatsHotTile` inside the collection view `cellForItemAt` method.  Using both statements, you should wind up with cells with rounded corners that also have images with rounded corners

Comment: Okay, I didn't add a UIView to be a background so I think that should fix it. When I round the Cell itself it only rounds the MinXMinY and MinXMaxY corners

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using UICollectionView here instead of UIStackView as it supports dynamic data and scrolling by default.